# Jackson: Surround Inheritance with Tags

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have two classes that I want to serialize to JSON. Using Jackson, is there any way to surround each object in the inheritance tree with a start and end tag?

For Example:

```java
public class Foo {
  int barVal;
}

public class Bar extends Foo {
  int fooVal;
}
```

I want the output of this serialization to be

```
{
   START_FOO: null,
   fooVal: 0,
   END_FOO: null,
   START_Bar: null,
   barVal: 0,
   END_BAR: null
}
```

Comment: JSON objects are generally unordered.  That sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: While I agree that ideally I should not maintain ordering, Jackson does support ordering using [@JsonPropertyOrder](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonPropertyOrder.html). Unfortunately I need to match the result of my JSON serialization to another file that I can not modify.